# Is memcpy of array in C Vaxocentrist?

Tags: c, arrays, type-safety

Is a memcpy of a chunk of one array to another in C guilty of [Vaxocentrism](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/V/vaxocentrism.html)?

Example:

```
double A[10];
double B[10];
// ... do stuff ...
// copy elements 3 to 7 in A to elements 2 to 6 in B
memcpy(B+2, A+3, 5*sizeof(double)
```

As a related question, is casting from an array to a pointer Vaxocentrist?

```
char A[10];
char* B = (char*)A;
B[0]=2;
A[1]=3;
B[2]=5;
```

I certainly appreciate the idea of writing code that works under different machine architectures and different compilers, but if I applied type safety to the extreme it would cripple many of C's useful features! How much / little can I assume about how the compiler implements arrays/pointers/etc.?

Comment: (a) No, not really.  (b) No, not really.  You can look at the standard and see what it says.  It gives a lot of latitude to the compiler, for sure, but you have to be going out of your to run into major problems.  You can certainly nail yourself if you try; most people don't feel the need to try that hard.

Comment: The article at that link is long; what is the specific failure mode you're concerned about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The model on which `memcpy` works is defined in the abstract machine specified by the C language standard and has nothing to do with any particular physical machine it might be running on. In particular, all objects in C have a *representation* which is defined as an overlaid array of type `unsigned char[sizeof object]`, and `memcpy` works on this representation.

Likewise, the 'decay' of arrays to pointers via cast or implicit conversion is completely defined on the abstract machine and has nothing to do with physical machines.

Further, none of the points 1-14 in the linked article have anything to do with the code you're asking about.

Comment: Yes, it wasn't one of the points listed. That's why I wasn't sure if it was vaxocentrist.

Answer (score 0):

In C code, memcpy() can be a useful optimization in a couple of cases. First, if the array of memory is very small then the copy operation can often be inlined directly by the compiler instead of calling a function. This can be a big win in a tight loop that runs a lot. Second, in the case where the array is very large and the hardware supports a faster mode of memory access for certain aligned memory cases then that faster code can be used for the vast majority of the memory. You honestly do not want to know the scary details of alignment and copy operations for different hardware, better to just put that stuff in memcpy() and let everyone use it.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: Okay, the short answer is "no". This description details why you do not want to assume things about the hardware and how/when memcpy() can get you benefits without such assumptions.

Answer (score -2):

For your first example you're using the + operator incorrectly. You want to deference the element its pointing to. This is safe because both arrays are of size 10, and when allocating memory for arrays all the addresses are sequential with respect to element 0. Also you're copying doesn't go outside of the bounds of the declared array that you're copying to, B.

```
memcpy(&B[2], &A[3], 5*sizeof(double));
```

On your related point, you're making the same mistake, you'd want to do the following:

```
char A[10];
char* B = &A[0];
B[0]=2;
A[1]=3;
B[2]=5;
```

Comment: “you're using the + operator incorrectly” do you think?

Comment: I am justified in my usage of the addition operator. Pointer arithmetic lets me offset into an array. The question is whether that is vaxocentrist.

Comment: @BigEndian It is interesting that you understand the notion of pointer decay that makes `B+2` a valid argument to `memcpy`, but you choose to ask whether `(char*)A`, an expression in which `A`, after decay, is converted to **the type it already has**, is Vaxocentrism.

Comment: Right, I see your confusion. I know that it works for me. I've been using C for a long time. I just don't always know if it works on another machine, compiler, etc.